# How to find the maximum value in one column based on other two columns

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
Fitness Frequency   Class   Branch
0       116.35      A       5
1       352         A       5
60      502.66      A       5
0       28          B       2   
1       15          B       2
1.5     19          B       2
22      21          B       2
0       96          C       6
0.99    45.5        C       6
1.1     32          C       6
1.99    66          C       4
35      105.8       C       4
```

I would like to get the maximum `Frequency` value for each `Class` and `Branch`. The desired output is:

```
Fitness Frequency   Class   Branch
60      502.66      A       5
0       28          B       2
0       96          C       6
35      105.8       C       4
```

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
df %>% group_by(Class, Branch) %>% top_n(n=1)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Class, Branch) %>% top_n(n=1, Frequency)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate` to get the `max` per `Class` and `Branch`.

```
aggregate(Frequency ~ Class + Branch, x, max)
#  Class Branch Frequency
#1     B      2     28.00
#2     C      4    105.80
#3     A      5    502.66
#4     C      6     96.00
```